# LeftHand P4500 Site Assignment

Tags: lefthand

In my multi (dual) site LeftHand CMC, all of my storage nodes are assigned to one of the two sites, but none of my servers are. I was advised by a storage engineer that this was not necessary; however, we are seeing some performance issues and wondering whether this is related (i.e. iSCSI traffic unneccessarily spanning the site link).

Should these servers be assigned to the sites? Would this improve performance? What are the risks of doing this?

On a possible related note, our ESXi servers are dual homed yet we have seen APD alets arising when a signle switch goes offline. Is this potentially another consequence of this configuration?